# Google Sheets - Creating a line chart with average closing prices over last 90 days?

Tags: google-sheets

I've been trying to create a dataset for a chart all day and its way beyond me so hopefully someone can put me out of my misery!

I'm trying to create a line chart of average closing prices for a list of NYSE stocks over the previous 90 days. To build the chart, I believe I need a column of average prices and another column of dates. I should be able to create the chart but I've completely failed at creating the dataset. All I've managed to do is cook my processor.

I have a Column (A2) of NYSE Tickers, and I've tried to build a matrix of prices per Ticker, per date which has taken 2 separate ARRAYFORMULA() functions.

I'm hoping there's a way to process all the data within 1 ARRAYFORMULA() and output the average price per date into each cell, but anything is better than what I've been trying.

**Here's some sample data:**

| NYSE Tickers |
| --- |
| HZON |
| VGAC |
| BSN |
| DMYD |
| SNPR |
| THCB |

(They won't all have data going as far back as 90 days)

**Ideally, the output would be:**

| Avg. Price | Date |
| --- | --- |
| $10.11 | 27/02/2021 |
| $10.08 | 26/02/2021 |
| $10.02 | 25/02/2021 |

(Average price of all NYSE Tickers in my A2 column for that date)

I hope this is possible and someone can help!

Thanks

**UPDATE**

The dataset is just input manually by me. Pretty much everything about my trial and error attempt is useless. But, I was using this to return historical close prices:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(GOOGLEFINANCE(CONCATENATE("NYSE:",$A2), "close", DATEVALUE(B$2)), 2, 2), "")
```

I'll try to demo what I was trying to accomplish: (best read from inside-out).

```
Output each average price+date to new rows {
-- For each day (X) - going back 90 days from today {
---- Get average price of array {
------ For each Ticker (build array?) {
-------- Get close price of Ticker on (X) date {
```

Comment: What about your data set is not producing the results you want? Where are you getting the data from? I'm not sure but are you asking about how to fit 3 dimensional data into 2 dimensions? To answer properly we would probably need a raw data set, seeing what you have tried so far, and understanding what result you want.

Comment: Hey, I've just updated the question to hopefully add some clarity. Thanks!

Comment: The sample data you have posted is just the names, no dates. The formula just gives me an error because it references cells that I don't have (the dates). Maybe its best if you create a new sheet with some of the data and a sample of what you want the output to be and share it publicly here. I know you are not happy with anything you've done so far but I can't just build everything for you. It sounds to me like you will need to break this question up into multiple small ones because at the moment it seems like you want sheet setup, formulas written _and_ a script written.

Comment: Plus the ticker values you seem to be using are getting "not exists" errors from Google, i.e NYSE:HZON